# jQuery toggle single div with two different triggers

Tags: jquery, html, triggers, hyperlink, toggle

I have limited knowledge of jQuery...I need help with this specific instance of a single div to be toggled when one of two triggers is clicked. The problem right now is that if one trigger is used, you have to click twice to get the other trigger to work.

Here is my jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    jQuery(".move").toggle(function(){
        jQuery(".contact-container").slideDown('fast'); 
    }, function () {
        jQuery(".contact-container").slideUp('fast');
});
```

});

My HTML is roughly this:

```
<div class="contact-container"></div>
<ul>
    <li class="trigger"></li>
</ul>
<a class="trigger"></a>
```

If you would like to see this on the development site, you can view it here (triggers are the "contact" button in the upper-right corner and the "contact" link in the footer): [Site Link](http://sharonehakman.com.s118336.gridserver.com)

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your problem. You want to have a div toggle (you mean slide?) when one of two triggers (you mean events?) is clicked (how do you click a trigger?). I'm just a little confused.

Comment: I don't speak jQuery/JavaScript...sorry. But I got my answer below, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I get the question, and I have no intention of going through your wordpress site to look at code, but try :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".move").on('click', function(){
        $(".contact-container").slideToggle('fast'); 
    });
});
```

Should work fine if both trigger element has the class ".move", otherwise just add that class to both trigger elements !

The reason it does'nt work now is because the toggle function keeps track of states for two different elements with the class ".move", but does not know it the slided ".contact-container" element is visible or not. Using slideToggle instead will fix that.

Comment: Thanks! I knew that was the issue...just didn't know how to fix it. jQuery gives me nightmares.

Comment: @JasonTowne - actually, it took you around ten minutes to edit it so it looks just like mine :-) .....

Comment: @adeneo Heh, I did edit my post to include your `slideToggle()` method. (Never knew about that one!) The rest of it was to try and get my original example: http://jsfiddle.net/aG8p3/ to match the code example RevCocnept posted.

Answer (score 0):

**First, [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aG8p3/2/).**

You can use jQuery's [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method to do this. It will automatically show or hide the element as necessary.

You can also set the `click` handler by class rather than by specific ID. That way whenever any element with that class (in my example below, I used `toggle-button`) it will call the click handler function.

**Update:** I changed my example to match the sample code you posted above.

```
<ul>
    <li class="trigger">Trigger 1</li>
</ul>
<a class="trigger">Trigger 2</a>

<div style="height: 400px; width: 400px; background-color:red;" class="contact-container"></div>
```

​

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.trigger').on('click', function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
        $('.contact-container').slideToggle('fast');
    });
});​
```