# jquery toggle with multiple triggers

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have a jquery toggle that I need to be triggered with 3 separate triggers. I found this:
[jQuery toggle single div with two different triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570094/jquery-toggle-single-div-with-two-different-triggers)

...but I need the toggle to animate to specific heights. Here is my current code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function(){
$(".nav-toggle").toggle(function(){
    $("#main-nav-dropdown").animate({height:146},500);
},function(){
    $("#main-nav-dropdown").animate({height:20},500);
});
});
</script>
```

and the html

```
<div id="main-nav-dropdown">
    <div class="capsule">

            <nav id="main-nav">
            <ul>

                <li><span class="nav-toggle">1</span>
                </li>
                <li><span class="nav-toggle">2</span>           
                </li>
                <li><span class="nav-toggle">3</span>               
                </li>

                <li class="last"><a href="">4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

    </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want to do what you want to do...so I won't ask, instead, I"ll just deliver.

```
$(".nav-toggle").toggle(function(){
  var pI = $(this).parent().parent().find($(this).parent()).index(),
      toggleHeight;

  switch(pI){
    case 0:
        toggleHeight = "146"
        break;    
    case 1:
        toggleHeight = "380"
        break;  
    case 2:
        toggleHeight = "550"
        break;        

    case 'default' :
        toggleHeight = "146"
        //fallback solution if for some reason we can't get the index.
        break;       
  }

  $("#main-nav-dropdown").animate({height:toggleHeight},500); 

},function(){
    $("#main-nav-dropdown").animate({height:20},500);
});
```

Basically, `var pI` checks the index of the span's parent LI. If it's 0, then we set `togglHeight` to 146, if it's 1 *(or the 2nd li in the list)* then we set it to 380, etc..just utilizing a simple witch statement comparing indecies.

Comment: Thanks, but I am still getting the same issue where if the first trigger is clicked to expand the div, the second (or 3rd) needs to be clicked twice to contract it.